# web.xml error using glassfish(payara) server on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, web-applications, xsd, glassfish, web.xml

I use IntelliJ to run my backend for my project. I use glassfish server to run my project, but everytime I run my project I get an xml error.

- I have tried to add the xlmns:web namespace, but it sais that it is not getting used.
- I have checked other questions on stackoverflow
- Reinstalled payara like 5 times
- Reinstalled my project like 5 times
- Reinstalled IntelliJ

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="aquadinePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aquadine?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="ruta" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

glassfish-resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN"
        "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="H2Pool"
                   jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/hibernate"/>
    <jdbc-connection-pool name="H2Pool"
                          res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                          datasource-classname="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource">
        <property name="user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:hibernateExample"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>nl.aquadine</groupId>
  <artifactId>aquadine-jee</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>aquadine-jee Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
<!--
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
      <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.192</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.46</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
          <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
          <version>0.10.2</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>aquadine-jee</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

The error that I am getting is as follows

```
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/C:/Users/Ömer/Documents/payara-5.191/payara5/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_3_1.xsd; lineNumber: 281; columnNumber: 47; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [aquadine-jee].  src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'javaee:web-commonType' to a(n) 'group' component.
```

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and specify the Glassfish version.

Comment: I use payara-5.191 and what exactly do I have to show that you can see where the problem is coming from?

Comment: See the link describing how to provide the required data.

Comment: I added every xml file in my project above, there is no other code that I can show you, because the only code that has to appear is just a text whenever it succeeds to run. The problem is that this project runs at other classmates with just the same code and same project, but I get this error.

Comment: You should zip and share the project directory so that others can download it and try to reproduce the problem on their systems.

Comment: Please also provide full stack trace of the exception

Comment: From this link you can download my project as a zip file: https://transferxl.com/08j2XTt2DJxDM9